# rewrite engine for php app

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create simple rewrite engine to make my urls more beautifull. Currently I'm using this:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_/]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

So when i enter this url:

```
www.domain.com/fooo/bar/foobar
```

i will gete from php:

```
    Array
    (
        [controller] => fooo
        [action] => bar
        [id] => foobar
    )
```

I want to update this rewrite rule, so when after domain part of url is starting with 2-3chars it will create different array, like this:

from `www.domain.com/eng/fooo/bar/foobar`

```
Array
(
    [lang] => eng
    [controller] => fooo
    [action] => bar
    [id] => foobar
)
```

I created new rule:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,3})/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_/]*)?/?$ index.php?lang=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&id=$4 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_/]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

but when i enter `www.mydomain.com/english/foo/bar/foobar`

it gives me:

```
    Array
    (
        [lang] => eng
        [controller] => lish
        [action] => foo
        [id] => bar/foobar
    )
```

but I'm expecting

```
    Array
    (
        [controller] => english
        [action] => foo
        [id] => bar/foobar
    )
```

because of word "english" being longer than 3chars.

Can someone help me fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new rule has an *optional* `/` (`/?`), so will happily match something which has three letters - `([a-z]{2,3})` - followed directly by some more letters - `([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)`.

In fact, you have `?`s and `*` all over the place in those rules, when as far as I can see you want to check that things *are* there, not just that they *might be*.

Try removing the `?`s, and switching to `+` (1 or more) instead of `*` (0 or more):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,3})/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_/]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&id=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_/]+)/$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

If you want to match patterns where only some of the parts are present (e.g. URLs with 2 parts, not 3 or 4) then simply add separate rules for those.

(As an aside, the form `([some-range]*)?` is redundant anyway, as the `*` means "0 or more in the range", and the `?` means "0 or 1 instances of preceding group" - so you have "0 or 1 instances of a group of 0 or more".)

Comment: Thanks for giving me idea, the solution which work only needed to remove first question mark. Btw. controller, action and id don't need to be set. In case if they are not set, Loader class in index.php will fill them with default information(home for controller, index for action). But still, thanks! :)

Comment: @M.Svrcek As I say, I think it's better to handle that with separate explicit rules for 1- and 2-part URLs. Having lots of optional bits in regexes like this will only lead you into more odd edge-cases later, and make the rule less efficient to process as well.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I will try to remake them then :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a non capturing group on your first {2,3} block like this to ensure it matches your {2,3} requirement followed by a slash..

```
(?:([a-z]{2,3})/)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_/]*)?/?
```

Group 1 will always contain your two/three character match or be null

Comment: I dont want add languages explicitly, the problem in my code above is when i use controller for example "product" the rule will be translated like lang=pro&controller=duct...

Comment: Thanks, for trying to help me, solution was to remove first question mark after the language group :) Still thanks, man!